# Python converting an sRGB value to RGB

Tags: python, rgb, srgb

First of all, I PROMISE I've read a ton on this, including here, but nothing seems to come close.  I have three values to represent a color, all in sRGB space, and need to convert them to, well, "regular" RGB (where the values go from 0 to 255 in a straight line).

I try this code (recommended many places):

```py
def srgb2lin(s):
   if s <= 0.0404482362771082:
        lin = s / 12.92
    else:
        lin = pow(((s + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
    return lin
```

And while the values are *better*, they still are not the same values as I need (example: .4 input returns a 33 whereas I would need a 59, at least in terms of what happens when I manually enter RGB values in a program that generates the sRGB values and then look at it in my program that I need RGB values.  If that makes sense).

I get the conversion isn't all that straightforward, but the coding must be available *somewhere*, right?

Comment: What do you mean RGB where the values go from 0 to 255 in a straight line?  It doesn't make sense. To define a line you must define a metric. a linear sRGB? (linear in *physical* intensity, compared to normal *gamma corrected* which are nearly linear on appearance). Or you have some different colometric value to R and G and B?

Comment: (0.4, 0, 0) sRGB to Linear sRGB255 is indeed (33, 0, 0).

As @GiacomoCatenazzi pointed out, there is no such thing as "Regular RGB". I suggest you to use [this tool](https://ajalt.github.io/colormath/converter/) to find the name of your formats. It might help you to find the code you really need.

Comment: Well, all I know is when I go to a color picker inside of nearly ANY program (in this particular case it's Daz and iClone, but it also is the same in Photoshop, for example) the RGB values I enter do not correspond to the ones I'm getting programmatically (I know that sounds backasswards but it's those sRGB ones I'm trying to convert to those 0-255 linear ones and in those a .4 returns 59, not 33).  I'll see if that tool helps, but at the moment about all I can think of is to make a table (ugh) with all 255 values to look in.

Comment: Well, I tried that tool but it does not give me *any* of those values - when I use the color picker (again, inside of almost anything) and enter RGB values (which I assume are just *straight* RBG values, from 0-255) and look at any of the conversions none of them are *quite* right (the linear one comes close, but no cigar, which is why the code I get everywhere just doesn't work).  I think I'm just going to go ahead and create the table and use it - perhaps what is going on in Daz isn't any kind of normal color system (although I doubt it).

Comment: Are there visible differences? Every program may have different rounding. And probably the most correct way is to just use the exponent (as some program do, and as it should be done). That part is a leftover of analog television (which had BTW also "darker than black", and "whiter then white" colours, so we should not copy blindly (but visually it doesn't matter). Are you sure that 1.0 should have 255? (everybody use different scale, and bugs (especially on websites and simple tools) are widespread).

Comment: Yeah, 255 does equal 1 in the (what I assume) is the sRGB, and 0 equals 0.  And now that I've created the table (ugh) the values lower than, say, 120 are below .3.  We don't reach .5 until around 150, and then the table looks about right in a linear fashion (which is to say that values from 160 up to 255 do seem to be "even" in terms of increasing the .3 to 1.0).  But - I dunno. The table works but it's a brute force ugly thing and I KNOW there's a better way if I just understood this color space used here properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, folks, but I'm an idiot (in my defense, I'm a VERY old programmer - I was working in COBOL before Basic was a thing).

In my routines I had inadvertently mixed up Green and Blue - for some reason (although I KNEW it was "RGB") I had it as RBG.  Thus the colors were definitely off... but not due to what I was doing (as we all know, the computer just does what we tell it to do.  And I told it to misbehave).

I don't know if there's a way to just delete things here but if so (and if someone else can) please do so.  All the "normal" routines to change color space now work just fine in my program.

Comment: If the code you posted in the question had included how you called it, we probably could have pointed out the mistake immediately.

Comment: Yeah, my bad all around.  As I said, I'm old - and REALLY don't want to be coding anymore (but sometimes there just ain't a tool and you need to make it yourself.  But I punished myself - creating that table by hand was plenty punishment enough).

Comment: I'm old too, but that's no excuse.  I still enjoy coding, I do it for fun here on SO and elsewhere, in addition to a full time job.  The one thing that hasn't changed over the years is I hate making mistakes!